# Using openssl to check if root certificate in PKCS#7 is revoked

Tags: c++, c, openssl, x509certificate, pkcs#7

Here's `pkcs7_verify` signature taken from C/C++ library:

```
int PKCS7_verify(PKCS7 *p7, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, X509_STORE *store,
             BIO *indata, BIO *out, int flags);
```

It can be used with PKCS7 block (p7) and the section that it suppose to sign (in data).

I wonder how does this check detect if one of the certificate in the chain is revoked...

From what I know, revocation check can be made only if matching against another certificate outside the pkcs7 block, which is marked as revoked.

I checked the function arguments and found one that represent the list of store trusted certificates.

This arg should hold the certificate which is the issuer of the lower-most certificate in the pkcs7 chain. So my guess is that if this certificate is marked as revoked, we fail the check on `revocation` reason...

But what if another certificate higher in the chain is revoked ? how do I provide this piece of information to `pkcs7_verify` ?

Or perhaps there's another openssl method that decide if a certificate in the chain is revoked or not ?

UPDATE:

I've found an alternative way to check whether a certificate is revoked. In the example below we can see that `revoked_test.pem` is identified as revoked by matching against the list in `crl_chain.pem`. How can I do it programmatically ?

```
openssl verify -crl_check -CAfile crl_chain.pem revoked-test.pem 
revoked-test.pem: OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = xs4all.nl
error 23 at 0 depth lookup:certificate revoked
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the rules of the certification path validation is set in the `X509_STORE` structure you are passing to the `PKCS7_verify` function.

<s>[This example](http://itsjustsosimple.blogspot.com/2017/05/openssl-how-to-verifying-certificate.html) show how to build a complete X509_STORE and explain how to activate the CRL validation in the X509_STORE.</s> (the example is good for setting up the crl validation but not for the certificate chain handling)

The core functions are:

- `X509_STORE_set_flags`
- `X509_STORE_add_crl`
- `X509_STORE_add_lookup`

You use the `X509_STORE_set_flags` to tell the certificate store to perform CRL validation. The flags you need are: `X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK`. You can find all flags [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_depth.html).

You use the`X509_STORE_add_crl` to add CRLs for the validation. The CRL doesn't need to be from a root CA.

As an option to the`X509_STORE_add_crl`, you have the `X509_STORE_add_lookup`, to add a function to lookup for CRLs in any place (e.g.: file system, database, urls, etc.).

When performing the chain validation, OpenSSl will use the CRLs and lookup functions in the X509_STORE to validate all certificates in the chain. If any certificate in the chain is revoked, an error is returned.

It's important to add that [the X.509 certification path validation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6) specification doesn't include the validation of trust anchors (usually root certificates). All certificates in the chain under the trust anchor have to be verified, but the trust anchor is trusted because the verifier set it as so (i.e.: the trust anchor validation is made out-of-bounds by the verifier).

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for you response. I've read carefully throw the article you provided, but I still cannot figure out how should we detect if one of the certificates in the chain is revoked (not the root one). The store contains only list of root certificates, so it must be that the pkcs7_verify get this information otherwise ... perhaps you can elaborate some theoretically explanation as well ? thanks again !

Comment: The X509_STORE also contains the CRLs to be used in the validation and the lookup functions to look up for CRLs. I updated the answer to point that.